# How to make a program which takes a dict as input and outputs bank net amount?

Tags: python, python-2.7, banking

I am trying to make a program which takes a dict at input and outputs the net amount in a bank account.

I tried the following code but the output is wrong and I couldn't figure out why:

```
netAmount = 0
bankDict = {'D':300,'D':300,'W':200,'D':100}
operations = bankDict.keys()
amount = bankDict.values()
for i in range(len(operations)):
    if operations[i] == 'D': netAmount += amount[i]
    elif operations[i] == 'W': netAmount -= amount[i]
else: pass
print netAmount
# OUTPUT: -100
```

The input doesn't necessarily have to be a dict.

Comment: You can't have multiple identical keys in a dict.

Comment: of course, it is a dictionary... how embarrassing.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries don't store two different entries for a single key. So when you create `bankDict` with multiple entries with the key `"D"`, it only stores the last:

```
In [149]: bankDict = {'D':300,'D':300,'W':200,'D':100}

In [150]: bankDict
Out[150]: {'D': 100, 'W': 200}
```

You might want the transactions to be a list:

```
In [166]: transactions = [{"type": "deposit", amount: 300}, {"type": "deposit", amount: 300}, {"type": "withdrawal", amount: 200}, {"type": "deposit", amount: 100}]

In [167]:for transaction in transactions:
            if(transaction["type"] == "deposit"):
                netAmount += transaction["amount"]
            elif(transaction["type"] == "withdrawal"):
                netAmount -+ transaction["amount"]
```

You could even extract the transaction from a dictionary into a class by itself.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This explains why I got the wrong output. So I need a different type of input for this type of program.

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered that I asked a similar question before about robot position. The following code works now:

```
netAmount = 0
operations = ['D','D','W','D']
amount = [300,300,200,100]
i = 0

while i < (len(operations)):
    if operations[i] == 'D': netAmount += amount[i]
    elif operations[i] == 'W': netAmount -= amount[i]
    else: pass
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still pass in a dictionary, just change it to

```
bank_dict = {'D':[300, 300, 100],
             'W':[200]
            }
```

Then you'll adjust the account balance with the the sum of each value list for a given key.

Answer (score 0):

This question can be solved in a different way:

```
def calculate_net_amount(trans_list):
    net_amount = 0 
    for i in trans_list:
        if(i[0] == 'D'):
            net_amount = net_amount + int(i[2::])
        elif(i[0] == 'W'):
            net_amount = net_amount - int(i[2::])
    return net_amount

trans_list=["D:300","D:200","W:200","D:100"]
print(calculate_net_amount(trans_list))
```